# How to make the jqueryUI datepicker show up in a hand-made popup?

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker, css-position

I've already read the answers to the problems similar to mine:
in the hand-made popup with position:fixed; jquery datepicker doesn't show up.

My problem is however not solved with overriding z-index of the datepicker:
my popup is 600, and setting the .ui-datepicker to 1000 !important makes no difference. I tried to set it everywhere I could (in css of jqueryUI, in mine, in javascript, but without any change).

Eventually it looks like this after calling $("#date").datepicker();
http://clip2net.com/clip/m56531/1297199993-cliptj4770-4kb.png

So, the container is added, but not the contents, and z-index of the date picker is bigger indeed than the one of the popup. 
Is my problem different from z-index?

P.S. All works fine with datepicker inside the block which has position:static. But also a problem with absolute;

Answer (score 0):

Fastest solution is to take another datepicker: http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/

Not that fancy, not that cool, but at least works.